# Three JS Javascript Save Canvas as JPG with EXIF Colorspace

Tags: javascript, three.js

This function works great in three.js for saving a canvas image as a JPG snapshot. A few issues though. The image doesn't save with any exif data, no colorspace ect so browsers treat the image colors randomly when uploaded, it often looks very desaturated when uploaded to the web. Is there an easy way to add the exif data to the .jpg image when saving it to add the color profile sRGB IEC61966-2.1? Also, for some reason this doesn't work at all in IE? Throws the error uri is undefined, which it is. Can't figure out what uri should be. Thanks for any help!

```
function saveAsImage() {

    var imgData, imgNode;

    try {
        var strMime = "image/jpeg";
        imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL(strMime);
        saveFile(imgData.replace(strMime, "image.jpg");

    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
        console.log(e);
        return;
    }

}

var saveFile = function (strData, filename) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
        document.body.appendChild(link); //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
        link.download = filename;
        link.href = strData;
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link); //remove the link when done
    } else {
        location.replace(uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no easy way to add EXIF data as far as I know. Maybe check out the [code here](http://www.perry.cz/files/ExifRestorer.js). Also, [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/art388yv/) for my take on saving three.js canvas to image

Comment: I was afraid of that. I guess one could use JSON and pass the image data to a PHP function an do it that way?